# Showing the result of COALESCE into separate columns based from where they where retrieved

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with many NULL values.  Therefore I use the COALESCE function to retrieve the NON NULL values.  This works fine when the result of the COALESCE is to be placed in a single Column.  However I need to place the values of the COALESCE into separate Columns depending from where they where picked.

E.g. I have the following table.

[image: TAble A]

```
SELECT COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) FROM Table 1
```

Will produce:-

```
Column1
1
1
3
4
```

However I do not want that result but I want this result:-

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
  1    -    -    -
  -    1    -    -
  -    -    3    -
  -    4    -    -
```

As you can see I want only one field populated (that why I'm suing COALESCE but the result of COALESCE should be placed as illustrated,  NOTICE ONE VALUE PER ROW.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this result please.

Comment: what happened to 3 in col3 and 2 in col4?

Comment: Corrected the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

coalesce can be built with case statements.  You need something like the below:

```
select col1
    , case when col1 is not null then null else col2 end 'Col2'
    , case when col1 is not null or col2 is not null then null else col3 end 'Col3'
    , case when col1 is not null or col2 is not null or col3 is not null then null else col4 end 'Col4'
from table
```

Comment: upvoted this solution, it's simple and does not do 2 sort as Anthony Faull's does

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of `PIVOT`, `UNPIVOT` and `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
declare @t table(rn int identity(1,1) primary key, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int);

insert @t values (1,null,null,null), (null,1,0,null), (null,null,3,null), (null,4,null,2);

with a as (
    select *, ranking = row_number() over (partition by rn order by col) 
    from @t a
    unpivot ([val] for [col] in ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4])) p
)
select *
from a
pivot (min(val) for [col] in ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4])) p
where ranking = 1
```